# Moving javascript on html document

Tags: iphone

I have everything working how i want it. The only thing i cannot figure out is how to move the javascript to the absolute top left corner of the page. The program takes the system date and then compares it to two of the season variables. After it compares them it determines which image should be displayed.

```
<head>
<title>Date Compare</title>

</head>
<!--- 
    Made by Ben Mason
    Email bambammason@gmail.com

    !!! You may change this how you like but please give me credit if you do!!
--->

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var a = new Date(); //beginning of Spring
    var b = new Date(); //beginning of Summer
    var c = new Date(); //beginning of Fall
    var d = new Date(); //beginning of Winter
    var today = new Date();

    //Set actual Dates
    a.setFullYear(2012, 2, 20);
    b.setFullYear(2012, 5, 20);
    c.setFullYear(2012, 8, 22);
    d.setFullYear(2012, 11, 21);

    //compare today vs dates of seasons
    if (( today > a) && (today <= b )) 
    {
        document.write("<img src = Images/Spring.jpg>");
    }
    else if ((today > b) && (today <= c))
    {
        document.write("<img src = Images/Summer.jpg>" );
    }
    else if ((today > c) && (today <= d)) {
        document.write("<img src = Images/Fall.jpg>" );
    }
    else if ((today >= d) || (today <= a)) {
        document.write("<img src = Images/Winter.jpg width=320 height=480>");
    }

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this has nothing to do with iPhone development.

Second of all, just use css.

```
<style type="text/css">
.top-left {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
</style>

document.write("<img class='top-left' src = Images/Spring.jpg>");
```